# Partir un String y retornarlo como Array

Tags: javascript, string

Estoy intentando creando una función que retorne un String partido en cualquier número y lo retorne como un Array con sus partes partidas

Pero no sé cómo hacer para partir por un número cualquiera

Mi código que solo puede partir en 2 un String:

```
function partir(texto, cuantasveces) {
  var elmedio = texto.length / cuantasveces;
  
  parte1 = texto.slice(0, elmedio);
  parte2 = texto.slice(elmedio, texto.length);
 
  return [parte1,parte2];
  
 }
```

```
console.log(partir("holahola",2));

// ["hola","hola"]
```

Si lo parto en 3 sale esto:

```
console.log(partir("holaholahola",3))

// ["hola","holahola"]
```

Comment: En tu función sólo lo partes dos veces con "parte1" y "parte2", para lo que tú quieres realizar, implementa un ciclo que recorra la cadena las n veces que lo quieras dividir y cada recorrido, agregue el texto al array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno no estas mal en usar `slice()` pero ¿como lo hacemos n veces?, pues con un lindo ciclo `for` para iterar en las `n` veces que se pida y estableciendo un inicio y un fin para dividir la cadena donde `inicio = 0` y fin sera `fin = texto.lenght/veces` y luego cambiaremos estos valores según la iteración.

```js
function partir(texto, veces) {
  //esto nos dara las n veces que tendremos que partir el texto
  var elmedio = parseInt(texto.length / veces); //cambia el nombre a algo mas intuitivo
  //aqui se almacenara el resultado
  let final = [];

  //inicializamos los valores
  ini = 0;
  fin = elmedio;

  //iteramos segun las veces
  for (i = 1; i <= veces; i++) {
    partes = texto.slice(ini, fin);
    final.push(partes) //añadimos a un array
    //redefinimos los valores
    ini += elmedio
    fin = ini + elmedio
  }

  return final;

}
console.log(partir("holaholahola", 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

También se puede hacer con una RegEx.

Buscamos caracteres en grupos de `1` a `n`.

#### Ejemplo:

```js
function partir(texto, veces) {
  let largo = Math.ceil(texto.length / veces);
  return texto.match(new RegExp('.{1,' + largo + '}', 'g'));
}

console.log(partir("holaholahola", 3));
console.log(partir("holaholahola", 4));
```